# Error: Unexpected value 'GaugesModule in... Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic3

I'm new to Ionic. I made a project using an extenal librabry GaugesModules (https://github.com/MeetmeLeave/ng-canvas-gauges). I can debug the project in a real device without any issue but when I try to compile `using ionic cordova build android --prod` gives me:

> *Error: Unexpected value 'GaugesModule in /..../node_modules/ng-canvas-gauges/lib/index.d.ts' imported by the
>   module 'AppModule in /..../src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a
>   @NgModule annotation.*
>
> *at syntaxError (/..../node_modules//bundles/compiler.umd.js:1550:34)*
>
> *at /..../node_modules//bundles/compiler.umd.js:14504:44*
>
> *at Array.forEach (native)*
>
> *at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/..../node_modules//bundles/compiler.umd.js:14487:49)*
>
> *at addNgModule (/..../node_modules//bundles/compiler.umd.js:23050:58)*
>
> *at /..../node_modules//bundles/compiler.umd.js:23061:14*
>
> *at Array.forEach (native)*
>
> *at _createNgModules (/..../node_modules//bundles/compiler.umd.js:23060:26)*
>
> *at analyzeNgModules (/..../node_modules//bundles/compiler.umd.js:22935:14)*
>
> *at analyzeAndValidateNgModules (/..../node_modules//bundles/compiler.umd.js:22945:35)*

(For simplicity I'm using /..../ for my directories)

My app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { InicioPage } from '../pages/inicio/inicio';
import { MonitorPage} from '../pages/monitor/monitor';
import { InternalPage} from '../pages/internal/internal';
import { HistorialPage } from '../pages/historial/historial';
import { CreditosPage } from '../pages/creditos/creditos';
import { BluetoothSerial } from '@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial';
import { GaugesModule } from 'ng-canvas-gauges/lib';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { UsuarioProvider } from '../providers/usuario/usuario';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    InicioPage,
    MonitorPage,
    InternalPage,
    HistorialPage,
    CreditosPage    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    GaugesModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    InicioPage,
    MonitorPage,
   InternalPage,
   HistorialPage,
   CreditosPage    
 ],
 providers: [
   StatusBar,
   SplashScreen,
   BluetoothSerial,
  {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
  UsuarioProvider
 ]
 })
 export class AppModule {}
```

My Ionic Info:

```
cli packages: (/..../node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v8.1.4
npm               : 5.0.3
OS                : Linux 4.13
```

I'm trying to solve this issue, but I don't know where to start. I was reading some similar issues but the workarounds doesn't work (for example adding `"paths": { "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"] }` to `tsconfig.json`)